# adding a character to a specific position of the file for each record in Unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a fixed width file ,I want to add a particular character to a specific position of the file for each record.Fixed with file means my columns are not separated with any delimiter.Each column have a specific width assigned to it.
Suppose the below file which I have:

```
129876   Amit     h-no-344    Gurgaon   
687      Rahul    h-no-2798   Bangalore   
5789     Soumyajith-no-33467  Hyderabad
```

I want to add two blank character (for ex :"  ") at the 19th position,so that the length of each record now will be increased by 2.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you tell us your specific problem, and what you have tried already and why it did not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/.{18}/&  /' file
```

Comment: sed 's/./&  /18' file.txt command is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$19="  "$19} 1' file
129876   Amit       h-no-344    Gurgaon   
687      Rahul      h-no-2798   Bangalore   
5789     Soumyajit  h-no-33467  Hyderabad
```

By setting `BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}`, every nth field is the nth character. Hence, the 19th canbe replaced with `{$19="  "$19}`. Then the `1` is evaluated as true so `{print $0}` is executed, printing the line.

Comment: I have tried the above command specified and this is not working for me.

Comment: Uhms, what did you get?

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$19="  "$19} 1' file.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1                                                                                                           getting some syntax error.

Comment: Ok it must mean you are using solaris. Try to execute it with `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead.

Comment: Did it work with that awk, @user3111130 ?